# numpy iterating over multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I am very new to numpy and I am trying to achieve the following in the most pythonic way. So, I have two arrays:

```
a=array([[0, 1, 2],[3,4,5]])
b=zeros(a.shape)
```

Now, what I would like is for each element in b for be one greater than the value of the corresponding element in a i.e b=a+1

I was wondering how this can be achieved in numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is the following:

```
b = a + 1
```

But if you want to iterate over the array yourself (although not recommended):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        b[i][j] = a[i][j] + 1
```

Comment: I want 1 added to each element of a, and thus form b - if that makes sense..The answer iam looking is b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Comment: Ionut: Sorry, but I was looking to learn how to iterate over multidimensional arrays - although your solution does work for this situation..

Comment: Ionut: Thanks a lot for this! really appreciate this help. I have been trying to look around, but not much luck.

Comment: @user2152572 `b = a + 1` is the right answer. You don't ever want to iterate over an `ndarray` because it'll be too slow. Numpy is designed for 'vectorized' calculations: if you use Numpy routines (rather than looping) you'll get the result much quicker.

Comment: I have posted a code showing you how to iterate over the array.

Comment: @poorsod: I see what you mean..Do you have an example somewhere of how to do such vectorized calculations? So, what your saying is I cant write C style loops over indices of elements?

Comment: What poorsod was saying is that using the numpy routines is a lot faster then iterating through the array yourself, but you may do so if it's for learning purposes.

Comment: Thanks Ionut and poorsod for your valuable comments, suggestions and examples. Accepted the answer.

Comment: @user2152572 you _can_ do loops, over either the indices or the elements (see Ionut's updated answer), but it'll be an order of magnitude slower than using equivalent Numpy or Scipy routines. It's basically because Numpy's functions are implemented in C (and Fortran) so they can go much faster than equivalent code written in pure Python.

Comment: @poorsod: thanks again. I just find it difficult to comprehend without indices. For example, if I have a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and b=sum(a,1) and if I want to do a-b, how would one proceed to do this?

Comment: @user2152572 `a = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]); b = sum(a,1)` will give `b = array([6,15])` (because 1+2+3=6, 4+5+6=15). `a` and `b` are different shapes, so there's no straightforward interpretation of `a-b`. Imagine if you were trying to work this out on paper - mathematically, you're not allowed to subtract a vector from a matrix.

Comment: @user2152572 Be more specific about what you're trying to achieve, and we can try to work out what you should be doing in Numpy. It doesn't hurt to write it out using `for` loops to get your thoughts in order, and then translate that to vectorized Numpy.